# Build Failed in Sencha CMD

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have today downloaded and installed Sencha Touch 2.0, I watched the tutorial video and all was going well until I tried to build the App.

AT first I had a problem with Compass, the tutorial doesn't mention having to install Compass and therefore having to get Ruby running on your system, and then get the compass GEM installed, nevertheless I sorted that part out with no problem.

The build progressed a little further the next time I ran it, but still gave me an error, and this time I can't see any indicators as to what is missing.  Maybe I need additonal SDK's installed?

I am running Sencha Touch 2.1.0, Sencha Command 3.0.2.28 with Ruby 1.8.7 and a Windows 7 OS, the cmd output follows, if anyone has any pointers it would be most appreciated.

```
[INF]           init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF]           init:
[INF]
[INF]           -before-app-build:
[INF]
[INF]           app-build-impl:
[INF]
[INF]           production:
[INF]
[INF]           -before-init-local:
[INF]
[INF]           -init-local:
[INF]
[INF]           -after-init-local:
[INF]
[INF]           init-local:
[INF]
[INF]           find-cmd:
[INF]
[INF]           -before-init:
[INF]
[INF]           -init:
[INF]
[INF]           -after-init:
[INF]
[INF]           init:
[INF]
[INF]           -before-build:
[INF]
[INF]           sass:
[INF]
[INF]           -before-sass:
[INF]
[INF]           -sass:
[INF]           [shellscript]
[INF]           [shellscript] C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\resources\sass>compass compi
le --boring --force
[INF]           [shellscript] C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1450:in `compl
ete''': invalid option: --boring (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1448:in
 `catch'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1448:in
 `complete'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1261:in
 `parse_in_order'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in
 `catch'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in
 `parse_in_order'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1248:in
 `order!'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1339:in
 `permute!'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1360:in
 `parse!'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chrisepps
tein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/exec.rb:65:in `parse!'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chrisepps
tein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/exec.rb:35:in `initialize'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chrisepps
tein-compass-0.8.17/bin/compass:7:in `new'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chrisepps
tein-compass-0.8.17/bin/compass:7
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/bin/compass:23:in `load'''
[INF]           [shellscript]   from C:/Ruby187/bin/compass:23
[ERR]
[ERR]           BUILD FAILED
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurr
ed while executing this line:
[ERR]           C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:109: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]           jar:file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288/sencha.jar
!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:364: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicExcept
ion.java:43)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:104)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractComma
nd.java:182)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.SenchaCommandTask.doExecute(SenchaComm
andTask.java:69)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.BaseAntTask.execute(BaseAntTask.java:2
2)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:
413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Pro
ject.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.ja
va:1368)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTa
rgets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.j
ava:1251)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:72)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginComma
nd.run(BasePluginCommands.java:94)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginComma
nd.run(BasePluginCommands.java:98)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BaseNamePathCom
mand.run(BasePluginCommands.java:142)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execu
te(AppCommands.java:116)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:49)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:71)
[ERR]           Caused by: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:117:
 The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]           C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:109: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]           jar:file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288/sencha.jar
!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:364: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuild
Exception(ProjectHelper.java:551)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:44
4)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(Call
Target.java:105)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown
Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:
413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Pro
ject.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.ja
va:1368)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTa
rgets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.j
ava:1251)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:156)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.ant.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:80)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.command.ant.AntCommand.execute(AntCommand.
java:75)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:78)
[ERR]                   ... 31 more
[ERR]           Caused by: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:109:
 The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERR]           jar:file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288/sencha.jar
!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:364: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuild
Exception(ProjectHelper.java:551)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(M
acroInstance.java:401)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown
Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:
413)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Pro
ject.java:1399)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.execu
teTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.j
ava:1251)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:44
2)
[ERR]                   ... 52 more
[ERR]           Caused by: jar:file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288
/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:364: shellscript returned: 1
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(Exe
cTask.java:646)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTa
sk.java:672)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTa
sk.java:498)
[ERR]                   at net.sf.antcontrib.platform.ShellScriptTask.execute(Sh
ellScriptTask.java:132)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown
Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequ
ential.java:68)
[ERR]                   at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:19
7)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.
java:154)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown
Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequ
ential.java:68)
[ERR]                   at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:19
7)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.
java:154)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown
Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
w
[ERR]           n Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequ
ential.java:68)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownEl
ement.java:291)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown
Source)
[ERR]                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
[ERR]                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(D
ispatchUtils.java:106)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]                   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(M
acroInstance.java:398)
[ERR]                   ... 64 more
[ERR]
[ERR]           Total time: 12 seconds
[ERR]           com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The following error occurr
ed while executing this line:
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:109: The following error occurr
ed while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/xampp/htdocs/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant
/antlib.xml:364: shellscript returned: 1

C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp>
```

Comment: What's the actual command you're trying to run?

Comment: @arthurakay most likely `sencha app build production`

Comment: Have you been able to fix it? I am having the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have compass installed? You can do that here: http://compass-style.org/install/

Answer (score 0):

It seems your compass version is old. Try [updating it](http://compass-style.org/install/), as mentioned by [user799301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799301/user799301). It might ask you to upgrade to Ruby 1.9 as well.

Sencha Cmd is working for me with Compass 0.12.2 and Ruby 1.9.3_p286, but any version that is recent enough will do.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your ruby, compass and/or sass version are to old. This line indicates that there is a problem with compass:

```
...
[INF] [shellscript] C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\resources\sass>compass compile --boring --force
[INF] [shellscript] C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1450:in `complete''': invalid option: --boring (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
...
```

I had a couple of problems yesterday on Windows 7 getting the "sass build step" to run.

Basically what I did was:

- Install Sencha CMD version 3.0.2.288 from http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download
- Install ruby 1.9.3 from http://rubyinstaller.org/
- Upgraded the gem system by entering: **gem update --system** (version 1.8.25)
- Installing compass: gem install compass (version is 0.12.2)
- Install Sass 3.1.10, a dependency of compass. Check with **gem search sass** because if you installed multiple or older version of sass its possible compass could fail to build.

If you just like to skip the sass build you can also try to enter:

```
skip.sass=1
```

in the **sencha.cfg**

**Note:** I also had the problem that the build of a fresh generated sencha touch app failed even after I installed all of the dependencies this was because the app.css file in **{app.dir}/resources/css/app.css** was missing.

There are also two interesting pages which describes the build process I´ve found:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192169-Important-SDK-Tools-Sencha-Command-Update
- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command_app-section-3